# Почему после клонирования git log показывает не все коммиты?

Tags: git, git-log

Есть проект, есть, скажем, 20 коммитов, все это на сервере bitbucket. Как получить все это на другом ПК? Я думал создание клона как раз и сделает нужное. Но после создании клона, у меня по git logs отображается только последний коммит из тех которые были и новые. А 19 коммитов пропали, ну или не отображаются.

Comment: А вы запушили свои коммиты в удаленный репозиторий?

Comment: так не бывает :)
может на разные ветки смотришь, в одной 1 коммит, в другой 20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> почему то $ git log показывает не все коммиты... Потому что показывает только последние четыре...

Потому что все на экран не входят. Нажмите

- <kbd>space</kbd> или <kbd>D</kbd>, чтобы пролистать текст вниз (т.е. читать дальше)
- <kbd>B</kbd>, чтобы пролистать его вверх (т.е. вернуться)

Ещё вы можете модифицировать команду `git log`, чтобы на экран вошло больше коммитов, например:

```
git log --oneline
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all
```

Вот это я сам использую, через git alias.

```
git log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow ul)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```